# Sums of powers are integer numbers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

The following is the generalisation of a problem in an old high school mathematical competition. 
**Problem.**
Let $a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n$ be $n>1$ real numbers such that for **all** $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the following sum
$$a_1^k+a_2^k+a_3^k+\cdots +a_n^k$$
is always an integer.
Prove that $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)\cdots (x-a_n)$ is a monic polynomial with **integer** coefficients.

**My question** is whether this problem is a corollary of some algebraic theorem? Thank you for your time.

*Edit1:* I highlighted some points that seem to be overlooked in the statement and the comment given below by KyKy is incorrect.

Comment: This isn't true in general. See for example [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305143/what-is-the-value-of-a4b4c4?noredirect=1), where the sum of powers of the roots are integral but $ab+bc+ca=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $abc=\frac{1}{6}$. You may be interested in [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), which are identities relating sums of powers with elementary symmetric polynomials, and have some relationship with Galois Theory.

Comment: Yes it is !It follows from the Newton's identities.

Comment: @Kyky I think I should remind you that this property should true for $k$. Your examples collapses easily against this property.

Comment: @Lep'titbonhomme Not really, at least, it is not a direct consequence.

Comment: You are right, I have been too quick to answer, sorry for that.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h335001p15446428